# Plupload get uploader object (v2.1.2) for file reader

Tags: jquery, plupload

I'm trying to read the selected file with HTML5 File Reader.

```
FilesAdded: function(up, files){

    try{
        var file = jQuery('#'+uploader.id+'_html5').get(0).files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function () {
            preview.find('.text').fadeOut('fast', function(){
                $(this).siblings('img').prop({src: reader.result}).fadeIn('fast');
            });
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        uploader.refresh();
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
},
```

In the older versions of the plupload i could get the uploader id with `jQuery('#'+uploader.id+'_html5').get(0).files[0]`

But i have updated my pluploader version to 2.1.2 and it is not working now.

> Cannot read property 'files' of undefined

Any idea?

By the way, uploader is defined as plupload.Uploader.

---

**Solution with Files**

```
var file = files[0].getNative();
```

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to retrieve the added file that way. And it can't work if you are in a non html5 runtime. What are trying to do ?

Comment: My runtime is just HTML5 and as i told you, i was getting the file before the 2.1.2 version. I don't know which version that was.

Comment: It is because the html structure of Plupload is not the same in 2.1.2. So `jQuery('#'+uploader.id+'_html5')` is an empty jQuery collection.

Comment: Yes i was talking about that. :) I think somebody maybe already solved this problem and knows how to get with this version.

Comment: You should post an answer to your own question, and accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For who still searching an answer to this;

Solution is more simple.

Solution with files variable in FilesAdded method;

```
var file = files[0].getNative();
```

And done. You have the file object itself.

HTML5 File reader accepts and reads that easily.